# imported project - Gradle Sync error no trusted certificate found

Tags: android, android-studio

i was building this project in windows 10 (was working perfectly), until i formated and installed UBUNTU 16.04

now when i try to build to imported project, it give me this error:

```
Error:No trusted certificate found
```

i read here about changing the httpS to http at the gradle.wrapper.properties but  the result was the same

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

if i try do to a clean

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download javassist.jar (org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/javassist/javassist/3.20.0-GA/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/javassist/javassist/3.20.0-GA/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: was the dns server of my modem (was using google 8.8.4.4) after i changed for the OpenDNS, worked.

Comment: @EricLeschinski you want me to lie? thats the thing that solved my problem... anyway, yes this provide answer to the question, since it solved the problem, or i need to leave it without answer and let the people discover it by their own?

Comment: I'd suggest deleting the question, since it ended up having nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Switch to openjdk-8-* resolves the issue.

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-9-jre-headless
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```