# npm run android in react native giving build error

Tags: java, android, node.js, android-studio, react-native

After running `react-native run-android`:

> JS server already running.

Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'pusher'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not download protobuf-java.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found

- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.

> BUILD FAILED

I have installed SDK tools,have followed react native documentation properly,but still have hit a snag.

I am using Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Check this similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421340/gradle-no-trusted-certificate-found

Comment: @JustinusHermawan thanks a lot this solved my issue,I had to downgrade my java version to 8 from 9

Answer (score 0):

Go to your build.gradle file in [your project name]\android\app and under "dependencies", change the 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1' dependency to 23.0.0.